# Analytics data per country for more than 2 years

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I´ve created an google analytics segment with the demographic feature "location" equals "France". (in the menu behavior -> all pages)

Now I want to use this for the period 2014-2018 but I only get data for the last two years.

If i analysis without a location filter, I get data for the hole period.

Is there a way to get older data per country?

EDITED based on the answer from Ms. Easy:
The condition in the segment:
[image]

Comment: HI! Are you satisfied with my answer? Why do you not accept it?

Comment: Sry. I was on vacation. Now I´ve commented your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of Data Retention period in your GA property settings.

*Admin -> Property -> Tracking Info -> Data Retention*

I guess there are 26 months.

Data for "Country" is not available for the period before 26 months.

Comment: OK. 
Thanks for the information. Thus, the data are lost forever?

I`ve tried it with segment type "Conditions" -> country = "France", but there are also only data for the last 26 months.

Comment: @alexander-fire A bundle with `user` is lost. Are you sure that you use `sessions` in your segment?

Comment: I´ve created an segment with a condition under the submenu "extended". In this condition I add a new filter under the menu "further dimensions --> user --> country". (see the screenshot in the question)

I only found the "country" filter under further dimensions --> user.

Comment: @alexander-fire You are right, data only for 26 months is available for "Country". And very strange that if I use 2 segments to compare - one as you created and one default "All users" - data is restricted for "All users" segment too! Sorry. I'll correct my answer.